# Can you setup uvm_backdoor access for a single register in UVM?

Tags: uvm

I am trying to use the add_hdl_path and add_hdl_path_slice methods to configure backdoor accesss for a specific register in our register package.

Can you setup uvm_backdoor for single register or do you need to setup the entire register map?

I get errors like: 
**Block does not have hdl path defined for abstraction 'RTL'.**

Which seems like it is looking for the "RTL" queue of hdl paths for its parent uvm_reg_block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the hdl path for the top most wrapper of the reg model. After that you can set the relative path to individual registers and you should be able to access the registers individually.

top_reg_block.set_hdl_path_root("top_tb");

individual register

top_reg_block.block_level.reg.add_hdl_path_slice("dut.block.reg", 0, 1);

OR

top_reg_block.block_level.reg.add_hdl_path('{ '{"dut.block.reg", 0, 1} } );

Comment: I think you mean: top_reg_block.block_level.reg.add_hdl_path_slice('{....

Comment: Yes you are right meant add_hdl_path_slice ( updated above ) , though add_hdl_path will work too.